# Elastic5 Query with curl with range

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I have the problem that this query doesnt bring the information for the host fancyserver01, there are connections from other machines.

In fact, this query against a elastic5 instance does not match only one host.

`curl -XGET -u "USER:PASSWORD" 'https://elasticserver:9200/connbeat-*/_search?_source=local_ip,local_port,remote_ip,remote_port' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":"true","query":"beat.hostname":"fancyserver01"}},{"range":{"@timestamp":{"from":"now-24h","to":"now"}}}]}}, "from":0,"size":5000000,"sort":[]})'`

any idea where is my problem here.

Comment: Are you wanting an exact match on the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is the "-" char, wich brings me the data of fancyserver and live01 instead of fancyserver-live01

`"beat.hostname":"fancyserver-live01"`

and i have this quote like this

`"beat.hostname:\""fancyserver-live01\""`